# Combine 2 queries into 1

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ssis

Currently, I dynamically constructing an SQL query, depending on the result of another query, which is executed shortly before.

1st query:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6
FROM tab1
```

2nd dynamically constructed query:

```
string query = "Update tab2 SET";

if (!Row.col1_IsNull)
{
    query = query + " anotherCol1 = " + "'" + Row.col1 + "'" + ", ";
}
if (!Row.col2_IsNull)
{
    query = query + " anotherCol2 = " + "'" + Row.col2 + "'" + ", ";
}
else
{
    query = query + " comment = " + "'" + "some text..." + "'" + ", ";
}

query = query + " WHERE (";

if (!Row.col3_IsNull)
{
    query = query + " anotherCol3 " + Row.col4 + "'" + Row.col5 + "' AND";
}
if (!Row.col6_IsNull)
{
    if (Row.col6 == "empty")
    {
        query = query + " col6 is null AND";
    }
    else if (Row.col6 == "not empty")
    {
        query = query + " col6 is not null AND";
    }
}
//[...]
```

Now I was thinking, whether it were possible to combine both queries into one single query.

Is there something like an if-statement I can use?

**Update**:

A possible final query could look like:

```
Update tab2 set
    anotherCol1 = 'abc',
    anotherCol2 = 'def',
WHERE 
    (col3 = 'test')
```

Comment: Can you add the final update query ?

Comment: This is what I call spaghetti code. Delete everything and become from begging with clear idea what you want. Use parameters don't add manually values to the query. USing a stringBuilder is also a good idea like AntDc said.

Comment: If you must build a query like this - please use a StringBuilder

Comment: @Prdp: Please see my update.

Comment: @AntDC: For this relatively small number of concatenations there probably is no real benefit in using StringBuilder.

Comment: Can you explain in plain english what your end goal is? Ex: "Generate UPDATE statement from 1st query results where ...". Also, are you doing this in Control Flow or Data Flow?

Comment: @Shiva: I want to build an update query. It depends on the results of the 1st query, hence the if-statements. It's in Data Flow.

Answer (score 2):

Use `UPDATE` from `JOIN` syntax.

```
UPDATE t2
SET    t2.anotherCol1 = COALESCE(t1.Col1,t2.anotherCol1),
       t2.anotherCol2 = COALESCE(t1.Col2,t2.anotherCol2)
FROM   tab2 t2
       INNER JOIN tab1 t1
               ON t1.col3 = t2.col3
```

This is just a mere example you may have to alter the usage of Columns in set & Where clause based on your requirement

Comment: OP only wants the t2.anotherColx columns to be set if the corresponding t1.Colx is not null - so you may need to use something like SET    t2.anotherCol1 = COALESCE(t1.Col1, t2.anotherCol1)

Comment: @PaulF - I dont understand what is written in `c#` code. Based on the sample update query `OP` shown I have added a example. OP may have have to make some changes. Idea here is using *UPDATE from JOIN* syntax

Comment: In the C# code he is only adding the columns that need to be updated if the corresponding column in the first query is not null - so if t1.Col1 were null, then setting t2.anotherCol1 would not appear in the final query - my update to your solution would always set t2.anotherCol1 - either to t1.Col1 if it is not null, otherwise it would set it to the original value.

Comment: you could do '...anothercol3 = CASE WHEN col3 IS NULL THEN anothercol3  ELSE col3  END, ...'